# how to show array values instead of index in html 5 web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page in which i am creating an array now it is showing index like 0.pdf for naming but i want that if it index 0 then it should retrun name and for place o.pdf there should name .pdf as given in code here is my array

```
var ad = ['ADVOCIN PI', 'DRAXXIN PI', 'EXCEDE PI', 'FLUNIXAMINE PI', 'NAXCEL  PI', 'LIQUAMYCIN LA 200 PI'];
var con = document.getElementById('first_div');
var charr = document.getElementById('search_input').value;

var charr2 = charr.toUpperCase();
var str = '';
var j = 0;
var len = ad.length;
var break_line = '<tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr><tr><td></td><td colspan="4" align="right"></td></tr>';
for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    var str = ad[j];
    var n = str.indexOf(charr2);
    if (n == 0)
        con.innerHTML += '<table id="results2" width="100%" border="1" style="margin:-68px  0 0 -2px; top:190px; bottom:100px; left:200px;"><tr><td>' + str + '</td><td colspan="4" width="6%" align="right"><a href="presenter.command(\'viewPdf\',{\'path\':%20\'/images/pdf/animal/Beef/' + j + '.pdf\'});">     <img src="images/view.png" style="margin-left:-227px; position:absolute;"></a><img src="images/email.png" id="' + j + '" onClick=mytest(this) style="position: absolute;margin-left: -145px;"/><img src="images/include_in_email.png" onClick=one_chk' + j + '() style="position: absolute;margin-left: -68px;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="chk' + j + '" type="checkbox" name="click_1" value="" style="position: absolute;margin-top: 54px;margin-left: -73px; z-index:5;"> <img src="images/button.png" style="position: absolute;margin-top: 42px;margin-left: -87px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>' + break_line + '<img src="images/line.png" style="margin-bottom:-28px;"></table>';
}
```

here instead j index i want value name like DRAXIN PI.pdf like this

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
/animal/Beef/'+j+'.pdf\'});"
```

To

```
/animal/Beef/' + str + '.pdf\'});"
```

Comment: it is working but it shows all pdf names in alert but i want that in put search a then it show str of only a

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. Can you please rephrase your question/problem.

Comment: probelm is that in this way when i alert STR it shows all the names of pdf but as you know it is searching from array so if in search names are with A letter then str should also show all the pdf with A not pdfs of whole array

Comment: Your script works as requested. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KfLJB/) is a stripped down version to play with

Comment: Open the javascript console (firebug, developer tools, dragonfly - depending at your browser) or change `console.log(...)` to `alert(...)`

Comment: what if we have two items with A then it does not show i have checked your code

Comment: You have `var charr = 'e';` But `'e' !== 'a'`